# Ubuntu 21.04, Epson L380 inkjet printer driver not working

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I’m a Linux newbie using Ubuntu 21.04. All the details are in the attached image. Here’s is my current, not-working printer driver: epson-inkjet-printer-201601w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

After you review the image, I’d like to know where to locate an alternate printer driver that works? Is there a site that has alternate Linux printer drivers for common printers?

(Note, I installed an Epson Scanner Utility deb file and scanning works fine.)

aaa
.
[image]

Comment: For me at least they are tiny fuzzy unreadable pics.

Comment: When I click on the pic and then click again, the pic blows up to be easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed. After some trial and error and trying different printer drivers, I discovered that the correct printer driver for my Epson L380 is "Epson L382 Series - epson-inkjet-printer 1.0.0-1lsb3.2 (Seiko Epson Corporation LSB 3.2)". I installed this from the Ubuntu printer database in the Printer Settings menu.